# Unity Android game crash on update - Upgrading PlayerPrefs storage

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am developing game with 100 levels in `Unity3D` (5.3.1f1) for Android & iOS. 45 levels are published  already. Now want to release update with 100 levels. But while testing, when I updated market build  (version 1.4) with test build(version 1.5), I found a `**Force close**` at the begining of level  16. Upto 16th level I could play without problem. Log says,

```
2\sdk\platform-tools>adb logcat -s Unity

* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

--------- beginning of /dev/log/system

--------- beginning of /dev/log/main

I/Unity   ( 8720): Upgrading PlayerPrefs storage

I/Unity   ( 8720): (Filename:  Line: 133)
```

Is it something with player preferences? There are almost 100 player preferences used. I am taking  care to save all prefernces when they are set or reset. 
Logic for level 16 & above is same as that of levels 1 to 16.
If anybody is having any idea about this crash -**Upgrading PlayerPrefs storage**, please let me know.  Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could it be a memory issue? Since Level 16 is no different, it might just be the moment when it runs out of memory. Can you try removing it and see if it breaks at 17?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I did remove 16 & still Force close is happening at level 17 :(

Comment: Your update is probably having a memory leak. Some objects are created and never released, they pile up and memory runs out, I guess.